# Multiple cue points at the same time. From After Effects to Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flv, after-effects

I have created a composition in after effects with a video layer and 4 different shape layers. The shapes all move around tracking objects on the video. I want to be able to turn the visible property of these shapes on and off at will during playback.

I have converted their key frames to cue points, and then exported the flv. The shapes have key frames at the same time throughout the video resulting in multiple cue points at the exact same time.

In flash I am only able to listen to the cue point that is dispatched from the lowest layer of my after effects composition. So for example on frame 10, layer 1 and 3 both have a key frame changing the position of the shape. Using the script in after effects I've converted these to cue points. So I now have 2 cue points on frame 10. My program in flash will only hear the cue point dispatched by layer 1, and seemingly ignore the cue point from layer 3.

Is there anyway for me to listen to multiple cue points at the same time? Or am I going to have to go about this another way entirely?

Comment: Although having no experience with the issues you're describing, I'm thinking maybe you can use the cue points to send "messages" rater than using an event-like approach? Like "show_2_4" would show layer 2 & 4, while "hide_2_4" would hide them...

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I'm actually using the cue points to change the x,y,scale of the shapes. The visible properties are controlled via mouse clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any information that multiple simultaneous cue points isn't supported but trying to add two cue point at the same time code in Adobe Media Encoder gives an error – indicating that you should probably avoid it.

[image: Adobe Media Encoder error dialog box - The cue point cannot be the same as an existing cue point]

Another solution would be to collect all the transformations for a given keyframe and collect them in the parameter list for a single cue point. An example could be:

**layerChangeCue**

- `layer1` : `"x:123;y:456;s:0.78"`
- ⋮
- `layer4` : `"x:123;y:456;s:0.78"`

Comment: Hi, Appreciate your response. I think this could work, but is going to require me editing the javascript script file which is converting the keyframes into cue points.

Comment: Since I'm new to javascript this might take a while! Here is the script if you have any ideas.. [link](http://sdrv.ms/UNOS50)

Comment: Ok, so I've modified the script file (not as hard as i thought, very similar to AS!!) and now instead of it creating seperate cue points for each layer, it creates one cue point on the top layer but with all of the other layers properties. Tested in Flash and its working great :) So thankyou very much for the push into the right direction. I will sleep much better tonight :D @walkitokyo I can't seem to give you rep as mine is so low, but will come back one day in the future and do so. Thanks!